# How can I put section title numbers in a box

Tags: titletoc, titling

How can I put section title number in a box and I want the numbers to be shifted like this picture :

[image]

This is my code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{\llap{\textcolor{red}{\csname the#1\endcsname}\hspace{0.4em}}}                    
\titleformat{\section}[block]
{\hspace{-8.9mm}\normalfont\fontsize{14pt}{16pt}\bfseries\color{blue}}
{\color{red}\thesection}
{2mm}{#1}
{}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{2.8ex}{2ex}
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection {subsection}{2}{\z@}
    {-15pt \@plus -0.1ex \@minus -.4ex}
    {2ex \@plus.2ex }
    {\normalfont\large\rmfamily\bfseries\color{blue}}}
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\@startsection {subsubsection}{3}{\z@}
    {-12pt \@plus -0.1ex \@minus -.2ex}
    {2ex \@plus.2ex }
    {\normalfont\normalsize\rmfamily\bfseries\color{blue}}}                        
\begin{document}
\section{Section one}
\lipsum[3]
\subsection{Subsection one}
\lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

Comment: What you want is not very clear? Is it the section numbers in the left margin, or also the subsection and subsubsection numbers?

Comment: all, the section and subsection and subsubsection numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all can be done with `titlesec`. Note I used the simplified version of the parameters in  `\titlespacing*` (with a `*` to remove the indent of the first paragraph after the sections titles).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titlespacing*{\section}{-2mm}{*2.8}{*2}

\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\fontsize{14pt}{16pt}\bfseries}
{\llap{\colorbox{DarkSeaGreen}{\color{red}\,\thesection\,}}}
{2mm}{\color{blue}#1}

\titlespacing*{\subsection}{-2mm}{*2.5}{*2}
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\large\bfseries}
{\llap{\colorbox{DarkSeaGreen}{\color{red}\thesubsection}}}
{2mm}{\color{blue}#1}

\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{-2mm}{*2}{*2}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
{\llap{\colorbox{DarkSeaGreen}{\color{red}\thesubsubsection}}}
{2mm}{\color{blue}#1}

\begin{document}

\section{Section one}
\lipsum[3]
\subsection{Subsection one}
\lipsum[5]

\subsubsection{Subsubsection one}
\lipsum[11]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @Bernard.